# Can't sudo setup.py develop because of permissions issue

Tags: python, setuptools

I am running `setup.py` as root like this:

```
sudo python setup.py develop
```

I'm getting an error like this:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'blabla.egg-info/requires.txt'
```

Note, that the folder exists on the system and it has the following permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Nov 11 12:32 blabla.egg-info
```

What is to be done?

Note: The same error goes also for `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Does this file exist on your system ?

Comment: Indeed. I've updated the question.

Comment: I can only guess if the setup script tries to run something with another user itself...

Comment: Have you tried installing it inside of a virtualenv?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to write in that file, but the file is already used by another Program (vim, nano, notepad, another script...) ? I don't have a Linux anymore, so I can't try your command :/

Comment: No, I am not working inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, I've discovered a workaround. Installing the new packages in the ~/.local directory instead of trying to install in the global site-packages directory solves the issue:

```
sudo python setup.py develop --user
```

Comment: I think you don't need sudo.